# Using the normal distribution in an applied problem

Tags: probability, random-variables, normal-distribution, moment-generating-functions

A company that produces laundry detergent has a presentation of 500g detergent bags. The process of sending the pens is controlled and the weight per bag follows approximately a normal distribution with a measurement of 510gr and the standard deviation of 10gr and certain of the other bags.

- a) Suppose you take 10 bags of detergent. What is the probability
  that the most one of those bags has a content less than 490gr?
- b) The company delivers 100 bags to a store. How do you distribute
  the number of bags with less than 490? What is the probability that
  more than 2 bags have been filled with less than 490gr? If
  approximately distribution is necessary to answer the question.

My try:

- a) We got $X$~$N(510, 10)$ so if we take the transformation $Z =
     \frac{X-u}{\sigma^2}$ then we got $Z$~$N(0, 1)$ which is easier to
  work with. But then I don´t know how to calculate the probability
  asked.
- b) For be I belive that we got to use the moment generating function:
  $M_X(t)=e^{ut + \frac{\sigma^2t^2}{2}}$  but clearly in ordener to
  answer this question I need a)

Comment: a) We want to work out $p = P(Z>-2)$ because $(490-510)/10 = -2$.
Then we will do this as a binomial probability, $Y \sim B(10,p)$, $P(Y \leq 1)$

Comment: Makes a lot of sense. Thanks George!